# Unable to validate iCloud mail account SMTP connection error

Tags: pantheon-mail

I've successfully got my Gmail account loaded with an app specific password but iCloud account will not connect.  I've generated app specific password for my iCloud ID and tried filling the username with and without the @icloud.com appended; I've tried both SSL/TLS and START/TLS; all the above in all possible variant combinations.

All I get is the same "Unable to validate: ● SMTP connection error"

I've searched the "Mail" tagged answers in this and other forums and haven't found a solution.  What am I missing?

Comment: Hello Peter! Can we assume that you are using Pantheon Mail to send/receive email and is the app you're having the issue with? Also, I guessing you're using the server settings put forth by Apple found here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202304

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Using the Mail app bundled with Elementary installation media and all the coordinates given by Apple iCloud support,  and then making the changes they suggest and trying in all variant combinations.

Frustrating? Nah.

Answer (score 0):

do

```
host SERVERNAME
```

(where servername is what you'd normally input in the server name field of the SMTP settings)
then use the IP it gives you for the server name box for SMTP settings.

Answer (score 0):

Well, by now, you may have found a solution or have given up (considering this was asked 3 years ago as of posting this) But if you're still looking for an answer, or you're a user reading this having the same issue, I would say using Mailspring instead of Pantheon would be the way to go for now. Maybe this'll be fixed in the future, but for now, this'll suffice. https://getmailspring.com/setup/access-icloud-via-imap-smtp